# Remove block of text in vim with regex

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

I have a file with:

```
mr l 0x19600000 0x00004341
mr l 0x19600004 0x00004820
mr l 0x19600008 0x00003130
mr l 0x1960000c 0x00003920
```

I would like to remove the last part of each row. So in my example above I want to remove

```
0x00004341
0x00004820
...
```

and so on.

The file consist of about 4000 rows so I guess a regex should be the way to do it.I've been trying this in vim without luck so far.

So the question is how to do this?

Comment: For your own learning, it would have been helpful to include your (failed) attempts; this way, we can correct your misconceptions.

Answer (score 6):

You could move the cursor to the space before the first `0x00004341`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to enter visual mode, <kbd>G</kbd> to go do the end of the buffer, <kbd>E</kbd> to go to the end of the line, then <kbd>d</kbd> to delete.

Or, you could run:

```
%s/^\(.* \)[^ ]\+$/\1/g
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one simple way:

```
:%s/ [^ ]\+$//g
```

Here's some explanation:

```
  %      for the whole document
  s      substitute
  /      begin substitution pattern
         a space
  [^ ]   anything but a space
  \+     one or more of the previous pattern (must escape + with \)
  $      end of line
  /      end substitution pattern/begin replacement pattern
  /      end  replacement pattern (i.e. replace with empty string)
  g      perform multiple times per line (does nothing here)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want just remove last part:

```
:%s/[^ ]*$
```

If you want remove last part and its leading spaces:

```
:%s/ *[^ ]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing all the lines look the same, you can do it with a macro:

```
qq
0
3f <-- space
D
q
```

then:

```
:%norm @q
```

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. Now I have something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Also works:

```
:%s/\%>15c.//g
```

Deletes from 15th column to right.